# Get first/one $item->image JOOMLA

Tags: php, joomla

I have a problem on my Joomla website.
This is the code I am having some trouble with:

```
 echo '<div style="background: url(/images/'.$item->image.');"></div>';
```

This is the URL I get if my article only has one image inside:

```
 <div style="background: url(/images/my_image.jpg);"></div>
```

This is the URL I get if my article has multiple images inside:

```
 <div style="background: url(/images/my_image.jpg my_image2.jpg);"></div>
```

Both images are being picked up even if I only need one.

Comment: what kind of trouble do you have?

Comment: it picks up both of the image urls i only need one

Comment: Like .item->image. [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to make the string an array, and then access the first item in the array…

```
$imageArray = explode(" ", $item->image);
echo '<div style="background: url(/images/'.$imageArray[0].');"></div>';
```

This of course assumes that if there are multiple images, you always want the first.

Comment: Thats correct but do i have to make an array first ? and how do i make the array ? :)

Comment: In the first line, the [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function turns the string into an array.

Comment: Okey. it dosent give me any output :/

Comment: @user3437732 Bah, sorry about that. I forgot the first parameter in the call to `explode` :(  See the updated code.

Comment: Thanks but i still get the both image urls with that :/

Comment: @user3437732 Post exactly what you have.

Comment: I add this:

     $imageArray = explode(" ", $item->image); echo '<div style="background: url(/images/'.$imageArray[0].');"></div>';

And i get this if the article got one image:

     <div style="background: url(/images/image1.jpg);"></div>

And this if the article got two images:

     <div style="background: url(/images/image1.jpg image2.jpg);"></div>

Comment: Do `var_dump($item->image);` and let me know what the result is. The only way the current code wouldn't work is if `$item->image` isn't really what we think it is.

Comment: i get string(41) "image1.jpg" and string(127) "image1.jpg"

Comment: @user3437732 That pretty much confirms my suspicion. `$item->image` is apparently not a simple space-delimited string. If it were, you would have seen `string(21) "image1.jpg image2.jpg"`. You should check the Joomla documentation to see what exactly is returned by whatever is populating `$item->image`. Not being a Joomla expert myself, I'm afraid that's about all the help I can give you.

Comment: Okey :/ to bad for me. Thanks for the help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the [`is_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function:

```
if(is_array($item->image)) {
 echo '<div style="background: url(/images/'.$item->image[0].');"></div>';
} else {
 echo '<div style="background: url(/images/'.$item->image.');"></div>';
}
```

Comment: If the current output is actually as the OP noted, then you will probably have to run `explode(" ", $item->image)`, and then put the results of that in the `is_array()` check. It appears that `$item->image` is a space-delimeted string, not an array.

Comment: Okey how do i make an array for that ? :P